# how to assign char array to another char array with another size in C

Tags: c, arrays, assign

I want to assign an array to another array. Both arrays do not have the same size:

```
char array1[7] = "abcdefg"; 
char array2[3];
```

How can i assign three(3) values from array1 into array 2? I tried so:

```
array2[3] = {array1[2], array1[3], array1[4]};
```

and i´d become the following error message:

```
expected expression before ´{´token
```

I know that i can use (`memcpy()`) when the arrays have the same size.

I have more experience with VHDL and verilog. In VHDL it could look like this:

```
array2 := arry1(2 upto 4);
```

But i do not have much experience with C programing.

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with using `memcpy` when the sizes are different?

Comment: You can use `memcpy()` if the region is continuous (and not overlapped): `memcpy(array2, arrray1 + 2, 3);`

Comment: Just because you knows VHDL does not mean the question is about it. Removed tag.

Comment: @MikeCAT it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to do the copy at run-time, you can either use [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy):

```
memcpy(array2, array1 + 2, 3);
```

or just write your own copy loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) array2[i] = array1[i + 2];
```

Note that, depending on the surrounding code and your C compiler and optimization settings, these two methods may or may not end up compiling into the same binary. Specifically, it's quite possible for an optimizing compiler to both inline `memcpy()` and to transform the explicit copy loop into a call to `memcpy()`, depending on what the compiler thinks would be most efficient.

Also note that, if the arrays were of some type other than `char`, the length argument to `memcpy()` would need to be multiplied by the size of the element type in bytes. However, the C standard guarantees that `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize your `array2[3]`, you can copy the values like you do

Just do this,

```
char array1[7] = "abcdefg"; 
char array2[3] =  {array1[2], array1[3], array1[4]};
```

Comment: `char array2[] =  {array1[2], array1[3], array1[4]};` will suffice since you are not using a string initializer.

Comment: If you define like `array2[3]` instead of `array2[]`, it won't suffice

Comment: It will suffice just fine if you want a *character array*, if you want a `string`, then you need space for the *nul-terminator*. Your answer is fine for an array, I was simply pointing out you can leave the *number of elements* blank and the compiler will set it. So bottom line, it depends on how you intend to use `array2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed mean the assignment then you can use еру standard function `strncpy` declared in header `<string.h>`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char array1[7] = "abcdefg"; 
    char array2[4];
    size_t n = 3;

    strncpy( array2, array1 + 2, n );
    array2[n] = '\0';

    puts( array2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
cde
```

Take into account that if you want that the array `array2` would contain a string then its size shall be equal to 4 to store the three copied characters and the terminating zero.

Comment: Note that `strncpy()` will stop if it encounters a null byte. This is what you want if you're working with null-terminated strings (as this answer seems to be assuming), but if you're trying to copy binary data (which might contain null bytes as valid elements) then you want `memcpy()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows 7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char array1[7] = "abcdefg"; 
    char array2[3];
    strncpy(&array2[0],&array1[2],3);
    printf("%s\n",array2);
}
```

Output:

cde